# Using TensorFlow with Sage

Tags: python, tensorflow, sage

I've written something in TensorFlow that makes use of some nice group theory functions that work very easily in Sage (and seem prohibitively difficult to code from scratch). The Sage part works on its own, and the TensorFlow part works on its own, but I can't figure out how to get them working together.

Specifically: I can make a file test.py using Sage functions and run it from the command line using:

```
sage --python test.py
```

with no problem. But calling a function defined in test.py from a .py file using TensorFlow fails ("Import error, no module named Sage"), presumably because Sage (6.x) uses Python 2.6.x, while TensorFlow uses Python 2.7 or 3.3+.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but if I fire up normal Python (the kind TensorFlow uses), I get this:

```
from sage.env import SAGE_LOCAL
SAGE_LOCAL
```

which outputs `'$SAGE_ROOT/local'`.

However if I fire up Sage first I get this:

```
sage
SAGE_LOCAL
```

which outputs '`'/usr/lib/sagemath/local'`.

I just upgraded to Sage 7.0 if that matters (this didn't work in 6.10 either, though).

Comment: Hacky thing to try -- run Python that has Sage but not TensorFlow, take result of `import sys; print sys.path`, then run Python which has TensorFlow but not Sage and run `sys.path.extend(<paths>)`

Comment: @Yaroslav: Do you mean use the list that `print sys.path` outputs then append each of those strings to sys.path in TensorFlow's Python? That threw a different error, albeit still from `from sage.all import *`. I also edited the description above with more info.

Comment: Note: also asked at http://ask.sagemath.org/question/32743/using-sage-with-tensorflow/

Comment: @SamuelLelièvre: That's also me, I asked in two places because I'm not sure which of the TensorFlow or Sage sides the problem/solution will come from.

Comment: The Python version shouldn't be the problem:
```
$ sage -ipython
Python 2.7.9 (default, Oct 13 2015, 12:06:06) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something **NOT** to do (yet); don't just take whatever Sage install you happen to have and do:

```
$ sage -pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-any.whl
```

Even though this "works", it also had several worrying messages about upgrading numpy and six, which completely broke the numpy part of my Sage installation.  This was with Sage-6.9.

Which means you have to make sure you have a Sage that has the right versions of Numpy and six.  With the latest development version, we do, apparently:

```
$ cd /path/to/my/bleeding/edge/sage/directory
$ ./sage -pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-any.whl
Collecting tensorflow==0.7.1 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-any.whl
  Using cached https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.10.0 in ./local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from tensorflow==0.7.1)
Collecting protobuf==3.0.0b2 (from tensorflow==0.7.1)
  Using cached protobuf-3.0.0b2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel (from tensorflow==0.7.1)
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.10.1 in ./local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in ./local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.1.1-py2.7.egg (from protobuf==3.0.0b2->tensorflow==0.7.1)
Installing collected packages: protobuf, wheel, tensorflow
Successfully installed protobuf-3.0.0b2 tensorflow-0.7.1 wheel-0.29.0
You are using pip version 8.0.2, however version 8.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

And then I don't get any failures.

So one has to be careful, but apparently it's possible.  However, you definitely have to use it from "within" Sage; Sage-as-distribution wouldn't allow you to use your other tensorflow with it.

Comment: Trying `./sage -pip install https://sto. . .` returns `bash: ./sage: No such file or directory`. I can cd into the .sage folder, though. What is the function of `./sage`? I think I should have the latest development version, I removed the old binary and installed Sage 7.0 last night.

Comment: (At any rate, since I have the most recent version I tried the first command [`sage -pip install . . .`] and it's working now, thanks!)

Comment: Sorry, I had `cd`ed into the directory - I'll update.  (`./sage` is how you run an executable file in the current directory.)